# MaterialHeader paddingLeft can not be set

Tags: gwt-material-design

I would like my MaterialHeader, and MaterialNavBar to layout to the left side of the page.  Setting paddlingLeft(0) does nothing.  No matter what paddingLeft is set to, GWT Material Design will always set the paddingLeft to the width of the side Nav.  I am trying to have the navbar extend from left to right, with the SideNav underneath the nav bar.

```
    header = new MaterialHeader();
    header.setPaddingLeft(0);
    MaterialNavBar b = new MaterialNavBar();
    b.setActivates("sideNav1");
    MaterialSideNav sideNavBar = new MaterialSideNav(SideNavType.FIXED);
    sideNavBar.setWidth(280);
    sideNavBar.setTop(64);
    sideNavBar.setId("sideNav1");
    sideNavBar.setAlwaysShowActivator(true);
    sideNavBar.setShowOnAttach(true);
    header.add(navBar);
    header.add(sideNav);
```

When running this code, the navbar is always moved to the right by 280 pixels.  And the Header html element has a padding-left value of 280 instead of zero.

Inspecting the html shows the header with a padding-left = 280px.  That is the same as the width that I set the Side Nav to.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Your `MaterialNavBar` is named as "b", but you used `navBar` in `header.add(navBar);`. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

In order to put the `MaterialSideNav` underneath the top `MaterialNavBar`, you have to pick a `SideNavType` which implements `HasWithHeader` interface. It seems the best fit for your need is `MaterialSideNavPush`(`SideNavType.PUSH_WITH_HEADER`).  Here is the GMD [source code](https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material-patterns/blob/release_2.0/src/main/java/com/github/gwtmaterialdesign/client/application/sidenavpushheader/PushHeaderSideNavView.ui.xml) and [demo](https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-patterns/snapshot/#sidenav_push_header).

---

According to GMD source code, your `MaterialSideNav` shouldn't live inside the `MaterialHeader`.

Comment: Thanks you are correct. The videos at GMD sent me in the wrong direction. They probably need updating.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Starting version 2 we separated our SideNav types into different classes for better implementation.

So as @brian17han suggested that is correct but need to upgrade that to v2 , here is a sample code

```
<m:MaterialSideNavPush withHeader="true" ... />
```

or java

```
MaterialSideNavPush sidenav = new MaterialSideNavPush();
sidenav.setHeader(true);
```

For reference you can check all types in here
https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#sidenavs